# In Opaleye, how to insert to two tables in the same query?

Tags: haskell, opaleye

My database has two tables with bijective row correspondence (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964851/is-it-good-practice-to-have-two-sql-tables-with-bijective-row-correspondence) question). It seems this means that to insert a row to each table without violating foreign key constraints requires the two inserts to occur within the same query.

In the [Opaleye.Manipulation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.6.0.0/docs/Opaleye-Manipulation.html) module I see functions such as `runInsertMany`, which insert into a single table. However, these return an `IO` action and not a query, and I do not see how to combine them into one. Nowhere in Opaleye do I see how to insert into two tables, or an insert `Query` possible of combining with another.

**Can Opaleye insert into two different tables within the same query? How?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Opaleye insert into two different tables within the same query?

No, it can't.  I didn't even know that was possible!  If you email me (my contact details are in the README) then we can discuss your use case.